# En el caso de un `dup`, y de un `close`, ¿cuál de los procesos generados va a ser cerrado, ambos?

Tags: unix, dup

En el caso de un `open`, de un `dup`, y de un `close`, ¿cuál de los procesos generados va a ser cerrado, ambos?

Por ejemplo:

```
fich = open("fichtmp",O_RDONLY,0640);
close(0);
dup(fich);
execvp(respP[0], respP);
close(fich); //se closa fichtmp// ambos?
```

Comment: es posible que en vez de -> procesios generidos. quiera decir -> Procesos Genéricos. o -> Procesos Generados Saludos

Comment: No queda claro que tiene que ver el proceso que estas creando con el descriptor de archvio.

Comment: Normalmente despues de `execvp` no hay otro ejecución, porque el proceso nuevo reemplaza el proceso coriente completamente

Comment: ha. 
De acuerdo entonces no se hace el `close(fich)`?
Lo que quiero saber entonces esta cual de los fich van a cerarse por el `close` si no habìa el `execvp`

Comment: Pues normalmente despues un error en exec* no hay muchas opciones para reaccionar. ¿qué vas a hacer en caso de un error? Preveo que el proceso se acaba. En este caso todos los ficheros abiertos se cierran automáticamente.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

En el caso de

```
int fd1 = open("file", flags);
int fd2 = dup(fd1);
close(fd1);
```

`fd1` se cierra y `fd2` permanece abierto.

Ambos *file descriptors* (¿descriptores de archivo?) se refieren a la misma *file description* (¿descripción de archivo?). Ésta no libera sus recursos hasta que el último descriptor que se refiere a ella se haya cerrado.